# how to add text next to a radio button using javascript

Tags: javascript, button, text, radio-button

I am new to Javascript.  I have a question, how can I automatically add text next to a radio button using javascript. I have the following code:

```
for (var index=0; index<4; index++)
    {
        var text = "Hello" + index;
        var name = 'RadioButton' + (index+1);
        var radioBut = document.createElement('input');
        radioBut.setAttribute('type', 'radio');
        radioBut.setAttribute('name', name);
        document.body.appendChild(radioBut);

        var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
        var divIdName = 'my'+index+'Div';
        newdiv.setAttribute('id',divIdName);
        document.body.appendChild(newdiv);
        newdiv.innerHTML = text;

    }
```

It prints the radio buttons but the text is obviously printed below.  What must I do to get the following format: RadioButton + Text?

Comment: Please include the html output

Answer (score 2):

Div is block level element so it's gets rendered on the new line. Use some inline element like span or label instead:

```js
for (var index = 0; index < 4; index++) {

  var text = "Hello" + index;
  var name = 'RadioButton'; // + (index + 1);
  var id = 'my' + index + 'Div';

  var row = document.createElement('div');
  document.body.appendChild(row);
  
  var radioBut = document.createElement('input');
  radioBut.setAttribute('type', 'radio');
  radioBut.setAttribute('name', name);
  radioBut.setAttribute('id', id);
  row.appendChild(radioBut);

  var label = document.createElement('label');
  label.setAttribute('for', id);
  label.innerHTML = text;
  row.appendChild(label);
}
```

With `label` you can specify `for` attribute which would point to corresponding input element, this is good for UX. Also note, that it makes sense to give the *same* name for radio buttons.

Comment: The problem I now have is that the radio buttons are printed next to each other and not below each other. Any ideas on why? Must I add a <br>?

Comment: You can add one more container and append inputs and labels into it. Check updated answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help.  I have a heck of a lot to still learn.

Comment: No problem, everyone was a beginner sometime. Feel free to accept the answer if you want.